# Задание кодировки в HTML: meta charset=utf-8

Tags: html

Правильно ли то, что вместо

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

пишут

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Это правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, в HTML5 именно так и записывают.